# Elapsed time from two dates

Tags: google-sheets

How to display duration time between two dates to looks like :

```
A1 = 22.01.15 

A2 = 25.08.16  

A3 = "1y 7m 3d"
```

What code need for A3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M2 = 22.01.15    

M4 = 28.08.16  

M5 = "1y 7m 6d"
```

where M5 code is

```
=CONCATENATE(TRUNC((M4-M2) / ( 365); 0); "y "; TRUNC(((M4-M2)-TRUNC((M4-M2) / ( 365); 0)*365) / 30;0); "m " ; TRUNC(((M4-M2)-TRUNC((M4-M2) / ( 365); 0)*365 - TRUNC(((M4-M2)-TRUNC((M4-M2) / ( 365); 0)*365) / 30;0)*30);0); "d" )
```